# Visualforce: How to display user's account using the $User

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have a visualforce component which I use for displaying the user's name.
Currently I am doing it using the following:

```
!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}
```

Is there any way I can display the User's Account as well using this without writing SOQL.
I would not like to create a controller just to display the user's account and am hoping there is a simpler and easier way using just Visual force.

I did try `!$User.Contact.Account}`

But it gave me an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two things you may want to try:

1. Reference the Account Name from the [$User Visualforce global variable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm).

   `{!$User.Contact.Account.Name}`
2. If that doesn't work, create a new [formula field](http://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_formulas.htm) on the User object named `Contact Account Name` with this formula: `Contact.Account.Name`. Once you have created that formula field, you should be able to reference it in Visualforce using: `{!$User.Contact_Account_Name__c}`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know the first one will not work. Looks like Sf does not allow us to access next level objects. Will try the second option. I did not think of this.

Comment: Awesome the second solution worked. Was able to create formula field and view it on my page. Thanks. Marking as solution.